# Is it possible to add support in a MSI package to change the folder of an application after it was installed?

Tags: deployment, wix, windows-installer

The only way that I know of to change the TARGETDIR is to uninstall and then install the same application again. Note that I need to have the MSI package at hand for that.

I would like to add support in my MSI packages to change the TARGETDIR of the application after it was installed. This feature would be triggered by the *Change* option from the *Add/Remove* window. When choosing that option, beside the ability to change features, the user would also be able to change the TARGETDIR folder.

Is that possible?

Thanks.

Comment: As Chris explains this is impossible. Please explain why this is necessary, so we can determine if there is another way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Well, imagine a situation where an user wants to move the installation folder of an application while not having the installation package available. A natural path would be to go to the 'Add/Remove' window and select the 'change' option.

Comment: Are you thinking in terms of moving a large install to a new drive due to lack of disk space or what is the rationale for moving the folder at all?

Comment: I used to deploy Web applications using MSI packages. The MSI would extract the files, create an application in IIS and etc. The application folder (TARGETDIR) was configurable during the installation/upgrade (major), but not in maintenance mode. Some times an administrator would call me asking to move the application folder, for reasons I don't recall. Note I don't use MSI packages to deploy Web applications anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not possible.  All directory properties ( including INSTALLDIR, TARGETDIR, INSTALLLOCATION or whatever else you call them )  are immutable once they have a component installed that references them.  You have to uninstall anywhere from a select feature to the entire product (depending on which features have components using the directories ) in order to be able to reinstall the feature / product and give the directory a new value.